# Area of a Polygon doesn't evaluate?

Tags: regions, polygons

For an examplary plane polygon in space

```
p = {{-(2017/250), -(2553/250), -(53/20)}, {-(3929/500), -(1327/125), -(2629/1000)}, {-(7639/1000), -(5657/500), -(2211/1000)}, {-(1917/250), -(5657/500), -(1063/500)}, {-(1649/200), -(2553/250), -(87/40)}};
poly=Polygon[p]
Graphics3D[poly]
```

[image]

Mathematica won't evaluate `Area`

```
Area[poly]
```

[image]

How to get the numerical value of the area?
Thanks!

Comment: Could `CoplanarPoints[p]` giving `False` be the reason?

Comment: `RegionQ[poly]` is `False`. We have to use `poly // DiscretizeGraphics // Area`.

Comment: @Syed Probably yes, thanks. I only checked the planarity visual

Comment: @cvgmt Thanks, because `Graphics3D[poly]` works fine I didn't expect `RegionQ[poly]==False`

Comment: @Syed If I check coplanarity "by hand" the non-planarity is numerically very small.

Comment: My hand-waving hack is: `(ConvexHullMesh[p] // SurfaceArea)/2` since `(ConvexHullMesh[p] // Volume)` is almost zero.

Comment: @Syed Clever, thanks again

Answer (score 3):

- Just as @Syed have mention, the 5 points are not coplanar,we can also found this by

```
p = {{-(2017/250), -(2553/250), -(53/20)}, {-(3929/500), -(1327/
       125), -(2629/1000)}, {-(7639/1000), -(5657/500), -(2211/
       1000)}, {-(1917/250), -(5657/500), -(1063/500)}, {-(1649/
       200), -(2553/250), -(87/40)}};
MeshRegion[p, Polygon[Range@Length@p]]
```

> MeshRegion::coplnr: The vertices in the polygon Polygon[{1,2,3,4,5}] are not coplanar.

- This is must the main reason why  `RegionQ[Polygon@p]` get `False`.
- Up to now, besides of `DiscretizeGraphics[Polygon@p]`, I can not found anothere way to see the structure of such polygon.

```
reg=DiscretizeGraphics[Polygon@p]
reg//Area
```

> `0.460609`

- We verify that the five points does not in the same plane. We construct a plane by the first three points `p[[1]], p[[2]], p[[3]]`, and the distance of the remain points to such plane is positive means that `p[[4]]` and `p[[5]]` does not in such plane.

```
plane = InfinitePlane[{p[[1]], p[[2]], p[[3]]}];
RegionDistance[plane, p[[4]]] 
RegionDistance[plane, p[[5]]]
```

> `233317/(500 Sqrt[34077111373])`

> `151761/(500 Sqrt[34077111373])`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got the polgon  originally from a `ParametricPlot3D` evaluation and I'm still wondering why it isn't coplanar.